# Buttons switches in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, object-pascal

I have an action on four buttons. I need to make a down (checked) button if it's pressed and other buttons up (unchecked). My button is `TToolButton` and the property `Style` is set to `tbsCheck`.

Could you please suggest improvements?

```
LButtonName := (Sender as TAction).ActionComponent.Name;
   if LButtonName.Equals('btnVorigeWeek') then
      begin
        LSelectionType := 2;
        btnHuidigeWeek.Down := False;
        btnVorigeWeek.Down := True;
        btnHuidigeMaand.Down := False;
        btnVorigeMaand.Down := False;
      end
      else if LButtonName.Equals('btnHuidigeMaand') then
      begin
        LSelectionType := 3;
        btnHuidigeWeek.Down := False;
        btnVorigeWeek.Down := False;
        btnHuidigeMaand.Down := True;
        btnVorigeMaand.Down := False;
      end
      else if LButtonName.Equals('btnVorigeMaand') then
      begin
        LSelectionType := 4;
        btnHuidigeWeek.Down := False;
        btnVorigeWeek.Down := False;
        btnHuidigeMaand.Down := False;
        btnVorigeMaand.Down := True;
      end
      else
      begin
        LSelectionType := 1;
        btnHuidigeWeek.Down := True;
        btnVorigeWeek.Down := False;
        btnHuidigeMaand.Down := False;
        btnVorigeMaand.Down := False;
      end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I found better solution. All these buttons are located on ToolBar.

I can loop through the ToolBar and utilize the `Name` property on the buttons to compare with. So, I've changed it to:

```
  var
    LSelectionType, i: Integer;
    LButtonName: string;
  begin
    LSelectionType := 1;
    LButtonName := (Sender as TAction).ActionComponent.Name;    
    for i := 0 to ToolBar.ButtonCount -1 do
    begin
      ToolBar.Buttons[i].Down := (ToolBar.Buttons[i].Name = LButtonName);
      if ToolBar.Buttons[i].Down then
        LSelectionType := i + 1;
    end;
    ...
  end;
```

**UPDATE**

Finally, I set proper `Tag` property and set property `Grouped` to `True` for buttons and changed code:

```
  var
    LSelectionType: Integer;
    LActionComponent: TComponent;
  begin
    LSelectionType := 1;
    LActionComponent := (Sender as TAction).ActionComponent;

    if LActionComponent is TToolButton then
    begin
      (LActionComponent as TToolButton).Down := True;
      LSelectionType := (LActionComponent as TToolButton).Tag;
    end;
    // and using LSelectionType 
    ....
  end;
```

Comment: Or `tbDeclaratie.Buttons[i].Down := (tbDeclaratie.Buttons[i].Name = LButtonName);`

Comment: @SimonForsberg Thanks. I like your solution. But is this case what to do with `LSelectionType := i + 1;`?

Comment: yeah, unfortunately you'd still need an `if` for that.

Comment: @SimonForsberg. Ok, it is not a problem. I used your advice and add `if`. Looks fine for me. Thanks.